# How do I copy from a Mac OS X partition to my Ubuntu desktop via root access?

Tags: partitioning, mac

I've installed the package `nautilus-gksu` in order to open files on the mac partition via right-click.

However, I **cannot manage to copy files from my Macintosh HD to my ubuntu desktop**!

It appears as if I can only copy to the directory `/root`. However It is not possible to copy from `/root` to my ubuntu desktop.

Answer (score 1):

this seems to be a bug: Bug #858247 
between Gnome (GVFS) and samba. You can mount your MBP partition using:

```
mount.cifs //192.168.0.x/public /mnt/public -o user=myusername,password=mypassword,nounix,sec=ntlmssp,noperm,rw
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with permissions. You need to have enough permissions to copy files from your MAC partition to your Ubuntu. If your HFS+ partition(Mac's filesystem) is mounted during boot, you can edit `/etc/fstab` to suit your needs. Take a look at [Ubuntu Community Documentation - Fstab](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab). The following is an excerpt from it. Please take a look at the documentation carefully before editing the `/etc/fstab` file.

> hfs+ This filesystem is generally used by Apple computers.
>
> For Read/Write mounting:
>
> `/dev/sdb2 /media/Macintosh_HD hfsplus rw,exec,auto,users 0 0`
>
> Note: if
>   you want to write data on this partition, you must disable the
>   journalization of this partition with diskutil under Mac OS.
>
> For Read only:
>
> `/dev/sda2 /media/Machintosh_HD hfsplus ro,defaults 0 2`
>
> Note: if you
>   want to have access to your files on Ubuntu, you must change the
>   permission of the folders and contained files you want to access by
>   doing in the apple terminal:
>
> `sudo chmod -R 755 Folder`
>
> "Staff" group should have appeared in this
>   folder's info. You can do this on Music and Movies to access these
>   files from Ubuntu.

Comment: For some reason I cannot accept this answer in stackexchange. There's not green button showing...

Comment: I'm in a similar situation. When I browse network in Nautilus I see 3 available shares (looks like SMB, SFTP and AFC). I chose SMB and was able to navigate to the stuff on my MBP I wanted copied, but the actual copy did not work: the error message I got said "Function Not Implemented", which is obscure to understand. I suspect this has something to do with the way Fuse works with this share, but have no knowledge how to check it or work around it. Would appreciate any tips. Thanks!